# inner join multiple columns from first table to a single column from second table

Tags: mysql

I want to use multiple inner join in my two tables from mysql,

The table1 has columns "subject,examinationtime,instructor,proctor,room"

and in my table2 there are the columns 'subject1' 'subject2' 'subject3'

I want to show the subject, examinationtime, instructor etc from my table1 based on what the subject1,subject2,subject3 is in my table2

so far my code is

```
select subject,examinationtime,instructor,proctor,room
                    from table1
                   inner join table2 on table1.subject=table2.subject1
```

and so far it works for subject1 but if I try to add the subject2 the datagrid view goes blank

here's the code that I tried

```
select subject,examinationtime,instructor,proctor,room
                        from table1
                       inner join table2 on table1.subject=table2.subject1
                        and table1.subject=table2.subject2
```

I tried to use the 'and' but the datagrid view goes blank. I think I need to use an Alias but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: [edit] to format your question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Have you tried `OR` instead of `AND`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you simply need to switch from `and` to `or` in your query:

```
select subject,examinationtime,instructor,proctor,room
from table1
inner join table2 on table1.subject=table2.subject1
or table1.subject=table2.subject2
```

Comment: i tried using the OR and it worked. thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is your query, rewritten showing how to use table alias':

```
SELECT 
    a.subject,
    a.examinationtime,
    a.instructor,
    a.proctor,
    a.room
FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN table2 b
    ON a.subject = b.subject1
LEFT JOIN table2 c
    ON a.subject = c.subject2
LEFT JOIN table2 d
    ON a.subject = d.subject3
```

Ans here's a query that should produce the results you describe:

```
SELECT 
    b.subject,
    b.examinationtime,
    b.instructor,
    b.proctor,
    b.room
FROM table2 a
INNER JOIN table1 b
    ON a.subject1 = b.subject
        OR a.subject2 = b.subject
        OR a.subject3 = b.subject
```

Comment: I tried using the OR into my current code and it worked. Thank you for your help! :)